# Convenient directory handling in R

Tags: r, directory, setwd

Since I'm working with many subdirectories, I find `setwd()` pretty inconvient, as it demands from me to remember what are the current and previous location and change them back every time I perform different analysis. Things get more complicated when some paths need to be relative and other absolute.
I'm looking for a convenient way to apply the change for the specific fraction of code, as in Ruby:

```
Dir.chdir("newDir") do
  # some code here #
end
```

I've written such ugly functions:

```
path = list()

tempDirNew <- function(..., abs= FALSE){
  path$tempDir$old <<- getwd()
  mod = ifelse(abs == TRUE,
         '',
         path$tempDir$old)
  path$tempDir$new <<- file.path(mod, ...)

  dir.create(path= path$tempDir$new, showWarnings= FALSE)
  setwd(dir= file.path(path$tempDir$new))
}

tempDirOld <- function(){
  setwd(dir= path$tempDir$old)
  path$tempDir$new <- NULL
  path$tempDir$old <- NULL
}
```

and apply `tempDirNew('newdir')` before and `tempDirOld()` after each part of the code.
But maybe there is some built-in, convenient way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might like that `setwd` returns the previous directory, so that you can do something like this in your functions:

```
f <- function(){
   old <- setwd( "some/where" )
   on.exit( setwd(old) )

   # do something
}
```

This way, you don't mess with global variables, `<<-` etc ...

Answer (score 2):

Why not just store your starting directory as a variable when you start and use it to reset your directory:

```
mydir <- getwd()
# do anything
# change directories
# do more stuff
# change directories
# yadda yadda yadda
setwd(mydir)
```

Also it sounds like you might want to leverage relative paths:

```
setwd('./subdir')
# do stuff, then go back:
setwd('../')
```